# Excel 2013 Function that will return last 12 values listed in a column every time I update it?

Tags: excel, charts, indexing, vlookup, sparklines

As the title describes I am attempting to find a function that will return the last 12 values of column. The catch is that a new value will be added to the column on every month and I need the values to update automatically. My end result would ideally be a 12-row table that adjusts as I add new data to the source table. From the new table I want to make a Sparkline that would than also adjust. Does anyone know how to do this?

I attempted to use VLookup as well as Index and CountA but neither gave me what I was looking for. They only returned the last value but I need the last 12.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Denzel

Comment: I tried the offset function...I didn't do exactly what I wanted because it did not show the previous 12 values. It only displayed one. I hoping for a function that would list all 12 of the previous months in separate cells!

Answer (score 1):

If your list starts at A1:

```
=OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-12,0,12,1)
```

entered into a 12-cell selection as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: I tried the offset function...I didn't do exactly what I wanted because it did not show the previous 12 values. It only displayed one. I hoping for a function that would list all 12 of the previous months in separate cells! –